# Checking if an UIImage is a landscape image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimage

How can I check if an UIImage is a landscape image (in Swift)?

I've tried this code:

```
if self.imageView.image?.imageOrientation == .Left || self.imageView.image?.imageOrientation == .Right {
            self.isLandscape=true
        }
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: if image width is larger than the height it is landscape...else it is protrait

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about:

```
let image: UIImage = //your image
image.size.width > image.size.height
```

?

Comment: sometimes it amazes me how the best answers are the simplest ones. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: simple yet explicit!